# Listening for multiple keyup events in Vue 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am developing a messaging app and i need to list multiple event listeners for the message box (textarea). When the user press enter (`@keyup.enter`), the message will send automatically. However, we want to allow user to add line break if they want to organise the message. So, we add `@keyup.shift.enter` (SHIFT + ENTER) listener to do that. The problem is when user press `SHIFT + ENTER` it call both `@keyup.enter` and `@keyup.shift.enter`. Is there anyway to prevent `@keyup.enter` event?

```
<textarea
   v-model="message"
   @keyup="typing"
   @keyup.shift.enter="newLine"
   @keyup.enter="sendMessage"
 ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this can be not use `@keyup.shift.enter` and inside the vent handler of `@keyup.enter` you check whether `shift` is also pressed, if yes, than call `newLine` otherwise `sendMessage`, like following:

```
methods: {
  typing () {
     console.log("typing")
  },
  newLine () {
    console.log("newLine")
  },
  sendMessage (event) {
    if(event.shiftKey){       
         console.log("newLine")
     } else {
         console.log("sendMessage")
     }
  }    
}
```

See working fiddle [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/b2s2tecL/).